# Should I bother calling dispose on objects which share lifetime of process?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I am aware that all objects which implement `IDisposable` should be disposed of as soon as they are no longer needed in order to free the memory used by their unmanaged resources.

My question relates to objects which I know **for a fact** will live until the host process itself is terminated. Would it make any difference if I dispose of them or not? Is there any chance of memory not being freed when the process dies? What about GDI objects? Would the GDI handles be freed when the process dies even if they were not disposed?

I fully understand that it is good practice to dispose of all objects anyways. I ask purely out of curiosity.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kimhamil/archive/2008/11/05/when-to-call-dispose.aspx Wow, people jumped on me like a pack of dogs on a 3 leg cat for saying not to dispose.  I have found it hurts more than it helps.  Shouldnt the lifecycle be manage by a container, not hard code???

Comment: @CrazyDart Thanks, that is an iteresting read, though it deals mainly with the question "Should object of type X normally be disposed". The more specific question I am trying to answer is "should object of type X, which should **definitely** normally be disposed, be disposed even if it shares the lifetime of the process?"

Comment: @CrazyDart When has Dispose hurt you? The link you give gives some examples of when Dispose should not be called, but the general rule should still be to call it unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the object (resource) in question.

When a process terminates all unmanaged memory, filehandles and other OS resources will be released, even if the associated finalizers failed to run.

But I'm not so sure about db handles, named-mutexes etc.

So before you could consider it safe to *not* call Dispose, you would have to know about the resource type and how it relates to the process. Much easier to just call Dispose() out of general principle.

But it is a theoretical argument, most classes will use `SafeHandle : CriticalFinalizerObject` . So I don't think it ever is a real practical problem.

Comment: By default, every object that has a finalizer will have its finalizer run. It's the opposite that you can control from your code: your `Dispose` can call `GC.SuppressFinalize` to signal that the finalizer is no longer necessary. (Edit: Actually, I think every object does have a finalizer, but by default it does nothing.)

Comment: @hvd - in theory, a normal finalizer could be skipped by the GC.

Comment: @hvd - "I think every object does have a finalizer" correct, "but by default it does nothing". Also correct, and very fortunate. Real finalizers are expensive.

Comment: Agreed, it's known as the as-if rule in C, but the principle applies to other languages and environments equally: if a program cannot tell that the finalizer hasn't run, because the finalizer has no side effects whatsoever, then the finalizer doesn't have to run.

Comment: When an object which overrides `Finalize` is created, a special kind of weak reference to it is created and stored in a list of objects which override `Finalize` along with some other bookkeeping information.  Even if the object immediately calls `GC.SuppressFinalize()` on itself, that will not avoid the work the system had to do setting up that reference, nor will it allow the bookkeeping information to be released until the object itself is collected.  Objects which do not override `Finalize` are never placed on the list, and generally do not need to have the bookkeeping information created.

Answer (score 2):

No.  By *design*, IDisposable is available to allow a program to release an unmanaged resource early, earlier than it could be done by the finalizer.  Which runs at a fairly unpredictable time, usually *later* whenever a garbage collection is performed.  You cannot predict when that happens.

There's no point in disposing at program exit, the finalizer is guaranteed to run just before the AppDomain is unloaded and the process shuts down.

That's said, there is some IDisposable abuse about, code that actually *expects* you to call it.  But that's typically based on the *using* statement, so not so likely you'll run into that.

Comment: Finalizers are not guaranteed to run at program exit.  The system is guaranteed to make some effort to run them, but that doesn't mean they will actually get executed.  Finalizers are really icky, and most objects really shouldn't have them.