# How to release all objects from memory

Tags: .net, dispose

I have a couple of questions about non-managed memory usage in .NET.

My situation is I have taken over a massive project which is failing. I'm actually looking for a few nasty hacks just to keep it ticking over so I can start investigating properly.

I'm certain my issue is, when my module runs it doesn't clean up properly. The code is full of MemoryStreams not being disposed of or not `using`.

So, I would like to know 2 things

1) When my program stops can I assume that everything which is non-managed is now forgotten about by the .net program but still alive and kicking? How does it eventually 'die' (other than a reboot).

2) Is there any magical class which says "Dispose Everything Which Was Called From This .dll" ?

Comment: `MemoryStream` not being disposed generally isn't a problem, unless you're remoting...

Comment: Disposing memory streams will not have any effect.  Use proper tooling to debug memory issues, get yourself a good memory profiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet, This program runs over multiple servers, but all are on lease lines making them 'private' so not sure if this still classes as remote?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675893/should-i-bother-calling-dispose-on-objects-which-share-lifetime-of-process

Comment: @Rotem - Thank you, this is brilliant, let's close this as a dupe

Comment: @DaveRook: That's not really what would distinguish it - unless you're using .NET remoting to "send" a MemoryStream to another computer, it's not remoting, and disposing of the stream will do very little.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I had miss-understood. In that case you are correct, it isn't.